# How do report a typo in the "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" help center page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, spelling

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> For more information on how to debug your program so you can create a minimal example, [Eric Lippert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) has a fantastic blog post on the subject: [*How do debug small programs*](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

The link to the blog post should be "How to debug small programs".

Comment: Write a question on meta _and tell us where the typo is_. (I'm not seeing the problem.)

Comment: @JonEricson Heh. How *to* debug.

Comment: @Anna Lear: I honestly re-read it half-a-dozen times and still couldn't spot the error. :-/

Comment: @JonEricson Yeah, took me a bit as well. Opening up the help page helped. :)

Comment: You report it here on Meta. And not in form of quiz.

Comment: @Jon same happened to me. Had to use Notepad-Compare-Hack to find it, guess we just overlook link titles!

Comment: +1 for the [original title](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/227956/1).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Original title sort-of reinstated.

Comment: @michaelb958 oh my, missed the irony. Kudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Report it here on meta... sort of like you just did, but maybe along with being more explicity about what the typo is so that mods don't have to go hunting.

That said, this particular typo is fixed now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Yeah, could probably have been clearer. Sorry about that.