# I found your semicolon again

Tags: bug, status-completed, close-dialog

In [Typo on the Close Votes review audit failure message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/218456/223030), the blame is assigned to a semicolon misplaced during a game of "who can spin the wheel of blame the fastest". [I asked in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218456/typo-on-the-close-votes-review-audit-failure-message#comment738232_225773):

> Did you spin the wheel to determine whose fault it was? If so, do we get to play *Where's `;`* again?

Well, regardless of what you are or are not admitting, I know you did.

> [image: You have no more close votes today; come back in 1 hour;]

(Believe it or not, some of us do run out of close votes occasionally.)

Comment: I can't remember what it's like to run out of close votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I found your semicolon again

Thanks! I've been looking for that...

Comment: Can't work out what you're trying to say here - is this some sort of dig at me for [my other unclear typo report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/227956/223030)? `:(`

Comment: @michaelb958 Ack, not at all! Just playing off of your question title here.